# Call to a member function load() on null when loading a lang in new library codeigniter

Tags: php, load, codeigniter-3

**My Class**

```
class Language
{
    /**
     * @var Language variable
     */
    private $lang;

    /**
     * Language constructor.
     */ 
    public function __construct()
    {
        // parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Enables the use of CI super-global without having to define an extra variable.
     *
     * @param $var
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($var){
        return get_instance()->$var;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the user selected language for a specific page or defualt one.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_language($page){
        if($this->session->userdata('language')){
            return $this->lang->load($page, $this->session->userdata('language'), TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

When i call the get_language method from my controller like so :

```
$this->load->library('language');
$this->SITE_language = $this->language->get_language('account');
```

I am getting the following error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function load() on null
>
> Filename: C:\MAMP\htdocs\application\libraries\Language.php
>
> Line Number: 51

Comment: The error is due to `$this->lang` not being set anywhere.  Don't know CI, but worth checking how this is expected to be set.

Comment: As the ci variable is being loaded it should work don't know why its not working

Comment: hmmm maybe let me try that

Comment: Since there already is a `Language` library in CI, maybe what you want is to [extend it](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#extending-native-libraries)?

Comment: @msg trying `class Language extends CI_Lang` is also NOT working

Comment: ohhh god the variable that i was using `private $lang;` was the one that was causing the problem removing the variable and extending the `CI_lang` class seems to be working :)